# Control character STTY issue

Tags: terminal, signals, special-characters

I am changing control character (e.g- ^C) using

```
stty intr ^_
```

under root privileges. It changes successfully.

But when I am closing terminal and opening terminal again to check whether same control character is saved or not, its actually not. It shows its default value.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stty configuration is part of the specific terminal you're in, not a global setting. You will need to add the stty command to your shell configuration (e.g. ~/.bashrc) to have it apply whenever you open a terminal.